# Translating php to vba

Tags: php, vba

please I need some help converting this php line into vba
I don't need to validate $pre, I just need to compute the changes of any variables in this line (e.g: $dx+=$ay..)

`$pre = $dy % 2 && ($dx += $ay %2 ? 0.5 : -0.5);`

so basically this is my attempt:

```
If (dy Mod 2) Then
    If ((dx + ay) Mod 2) Then
        dx = dx - 0.5
    Else
        dx = dx + 0.5
    End If
End If
```

I ran some tests and it I don't get the same results with this vba code

Comment: In the second I condition probably you do not need to sum up I'll dx +ay. It should be just ay

Comment: Yes you are right, thank you :) - though I don't really understand whats going on - why does it state $dx += $ay ? you propably can't tell me without more background but it does overrite the value of dx to the sum of dx and ay right?

Comment: The `a ? x : y` part means, if a is true, x is used - otherwise y. the dx += .. is an assignment a the short form of dx = dx + ..

Comment: yes I understand this but what happens with the conditional statement `'$dx += $ay %2 `
for example `a+=b % 2 ? .5 : -.5` it will check if the sum of a and b is modulo 2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it should be:

```
If (dy Mod 2) Then
    If (ay Mod 2) Then
        dx = dx + 0.5
    Else
       dx = dx - 0.5
    End If
End If
```

Answer (score 1):

Seems like your second condition isn't correct. The PHP code says `$ay %2` but your writing `dx+ay % 2`

```
If (dy Mod 2) Then
    If (ay Mod 2) Then
        dx = dx + 0.5
    Else
        dx = dx - 0.5
    End If
End If
```

Comment: thank you so much :) it's working with your/eugenjoy's code